# Import CSV using Botton

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tkinter

I was trying to import a csv file into python using code like this, basically this code will using tkinter to pup up a window for user to choose a .csv file's location, then load to python by pandas.read_csv for further analysis.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def get_file_name(file_entry):
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    file_entry.delete(0,END)
    file_entry.insert(0,file_name)

def run_and_close(event=None):
    ######################################
    ## EXECUTE OR CALL OTHER PYTHON FILE##
    ######################################
    close()

def close(event=None):
    master.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing

master = Tk()
master.title("This is my Interface")

entry_csv=Entry(master, text="", width=50)
entry_csv.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)

Label(master, text="Input CSV").grid(row=0, column=0 ,sticky=W)
Button(master, text="Browse...", width=10, command=lambda:get_file_name(entry_csv)).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

Button(master, text="Ok",     command=run_and_close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, padx=5)
Button(master, text="Cancel", command=close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

master.bind('<Return>', run_and_close)
master.bind('<Escape>', close)

mainloop()

csv = pd.read_csv(get_file_name(file_entry=1))

print(csv)

*
```

But at the end, it shows me nothing, I am not able to load the .CSV file location into pandas, Is there any way to fix it? do I need return something in "def" part?
Thank guys for the help

Comment: don't you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should load file inside `get_file_name()` or in `run_and close()` - in current version it will try to load after closing tkinter window. But you need `return file_name` in `get_file_name` to use it as `pd.read_csv(get_file_name())` - without `return file_name` it returns `None` and you get `pd.read_csv(None)`. And don't use `file_entry=1` because it will try to run `1.delete(0,END)` and it makes no senese.

Comment: code `mainloop()` shows window and it waits until you close this window but when you close window then you run `sys.exit()` and it exits program so it never runs `csv = pd.read_csv(...)`. Remove `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mainloop()` shows window and it waits until you close window - and after closing window it runs code which you have after `mainloop()`. But when you close window then you run `sys.exit()` and it exits program and it has no change to run `csv = pd.read_csv(...)`

So first you should remove `sys.exit()` and use `master.destroy()` to close/exit only window, without exiting program.

Second problem: `file_name` is local variable and you have to use `global file_name` inside `get_file_name` to inform function that `file_name = ...` has to assign value to external/global variable instead of creating local variable.

It would be good also to set default value at start

```
file_name = None
```

to recognize if you selected file name or not.

And then you can use it after closing window

```
if file_name:
    csv = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    print(csv)
```

---

```
#from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

def get_file_name(file_entry):
    global file_name # inform function to assign it to external/global variable
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    file_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    file_entry.insert(0, file_name)

def run_and_close(event=None):
    ######################################
    ## EXECUTE OR CALL OTHER PYTHON FILE##
    ######################################
    close()

def close(event=None):
    master.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    master.destroy()

# --- main ---

file_name = None                   
                   
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("This is my Interface")

entry_csv = tk.Entry(master, text="", width=50)
entry_csv.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5)

tk.Label(master, text="Input CSV").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
tk.Button(master, text="Browse...", width=10, command=lambda:get_file_name(entry_csv)).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='w')

tk.Button(master, text="Ok",     command=run_and_close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='e', padx=5)
tk.Button(master, text="Cancel", command=close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w')

master.bind('<Return>', run_and_close)
master.bind('<Escape>', close)

master.mainloop()

if file_name:
    csv = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    print(csv)
```

---

**BTW:** `import *` is not preferred. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Similar result but with much shorter code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

tk.Tk().withdraw()
file_name = fd.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
                   
if file_name:
    csv = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    print(csv)
```

Comment: Thank you furas!! Thanks for your patient answer and it was well structured! You made it very clear and it really helped a lot! Hope there is one day I can as good as you!

Comment: Just one more question furas, I am wondering how did you learn Python? I am a complete beginner and could please recommend some book or video for me to learn python?

Comment: `Python` wasn't my first language (I already knew `PHP`, `C/C++`, and many others) so I needed only Google to search examples, documentations, modules. But [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python], (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) seems interesting at start. There are also places which I often see in Google results and I visit them as first: [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/), [Mouse Vs. Python](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/), video [sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex)

Comment: BTW: some examples (for different module) from my answers on Stackoverflow I keep on GitHub [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/) but they are without description/explanation - only some comments in code and link to original question on Stackoverflow where problem is described. Examples are grouped by modules.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems; firstly, you are calling variables/widgets created in the TK window outside of the mainloop. Shifting the line `csv = pd.read_csv(get_file_name(file_entry=1))` inside your `run_and_close` function fixes this. This is logically where you want it anyway, as you want it to occur when the "OK" button is pressed.

Secondly, you are calling the function `get_file_name` when trying to load the csv file. This won't work, as `read_csv` expects a path in the form of a string. Try printing `get_file_name` and see what happens. You can fix this by replacing `get_file_name(file_entry=1)` with `entry_csv.get()`

Below is your code, altered so that it works.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

def get_file_name(file_entry):
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    file_entry.delete(0, END)
    file_entry.insert(0, file_name)

def run_and_close(event=None):
    ######################################
    ## EXECUTE OR CALL OTHER PYTHON FILE##
    ######################################
    filepath = entry_csv.get()
    csv = pd.read_csv(filepath)

    print(csv)
    master.destroy()


def close(event=None):
##    master.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
##    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing
    pass

# Filepath variable

master = Tk()
master.title("This is my Interface")

entry_csv=Entry(master, text="", width=50)
entry_csv.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)
entry_csv.insert(0, "Test")

Label(master, text="Input CSV").grid(row=0, column=0 ,sticky=W)
Button(master, text="Browse...", width=10, command=lambda:get_file_name(entry_csv)).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

Button(master, text="Ok",     command=run_and_close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, padx=5)
Button(master, text="Cancel", command=close, width=10).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

master.bind('<Return>', run_and_close)
master.bind('<Escape>', close)

mainloop()
```